# List.Remove(obj) is removing the incorrect value

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, enums

I'm doing a code to remove one line from a `<p:datatable>` using a commandLink in the same line.

**XHTML**

```
<p:dataTable value="#{demandaController.equipeFornecedor}"
    var="equipe" id="dtEquipe" style="width:70%; margin-top:5%">
    ...

    <p:column headerText="Excluir" width="20%">
        <p:commandLink value="Excluir" actionListener="#{demandaController.removerFuncEquipe(equipe)}" update="dtEquipe" ></p:commandLink>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

**Bean**

```
private List<Equipe> equipeFornecedor = new ArrayList<Equipe>();

public void removerFuncEquipe(Equipe funcionario) {
    equipeFornecedor.remove(funcionario);
}
```

The method removerFuncEquipe(equipe) is called with the correct item value (inspected)

But...when i try to remove it by equipeFornecedor.Remove(item), it removes the incorrect value of my list.
What am I doing wrong??

**EDIT**:

```
public abstract class DefaultEntity implements Serializable {

@Override
public int hashCode() {
final int prime = 31;
int result = 1;
result = prime * result + (getId() == null ? 0 : getId().hashCode());
return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
if (this == obj) {
    return true;
}
if (obj == null) {
    return false;
}
if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
    return false;
}
DefaultEntity other = (DefaultEntity) obj;
if (getId() == null) {
    if (other.getId() != null) {
    return false;
    }
} else if (!getId().equals(other.getId())) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}

}
```

Equipe:

```
public class Equipe extends DefaultEntity {
....
}
```

The both objects ID is `null`, debugging the function `equals`, i saw that none of the IF conditions is satisfied, and then it returns `true`.
How could i fix that function?

Comment: Can you share the **complete** dataTable definition ?

Comment: Show the implementation of `Equipe`, especially the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods.  These must be correctly implemented for `remove()` to work.

Comment: @kocko, just realized that the problem is in Equal function, and this is the whole datatable definition, i just hid some basic columns.

Comment: @JimGarrison Nice catch! The error is in Equals function...it's returning true for different values.... I'm just not familiar with that function, can you tell me what could be wrong? Thank you !

Comment: So `Equipe` extends `DefaultEntity`, where `equals()` and `hashCode()` depend on `getId()`.  What does `getId()` look like?  Can two instances have the same return value from `getId()`? More important, what makes two instances of `Equipe` "semantically equal" to each other, and is this reflected in the superclass' `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods?